# Can't run ng serve because of error "Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'"

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have an Angular project, I can't run `ng serve` because it fails with the error:

```
dev@716a5115c45c:~/project$ npx ng serve
Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev/volume/cache/front-node-modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:12:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev/volume/cache/front-node-modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:13:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ruskline-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.12.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.18",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^4.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": ">=0.29.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.1",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4"
  }
}
```

`compiler-cli` is listed in there

When I run `npm i` I get a lot of `WARN` messages, maybe I missed something?

```
dev@716a5115c45c:~/project$ npm i
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@7.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@>=5.0.0 <8.0.0 || ^7.0.0-beta.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@2.29.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >= 3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/ng-packagr/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/karma/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 54077 packages in 14.168s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

UPDATE:
After @Melchia advices i have this error:

```
dev@e1f2820d1be5:~/project$ make start
./node_modules/.bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'symbol-observable'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev/volume/cache/front-node-modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'start' failed
make: *** [start] Error 1
```

Comment: update your `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: What about running the local version in your `node_modules` folder? You can do this by running `$(npm bin)/ng <command>` in your terminal.

Comment: @Abhishek, i don't have global @angular/cli package, i don't need this.

Comment: @Edric, i'm trying to run `ng serve` locally. My command is `./node_modules/.bin/ng serve`

Comment: @AlexanderKondaurov have you try `rm -rf node_modules dist, npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest, npm install` this commands?

Comment: @Abhishek, didn't help :(

Comment: @AlexanderKondaurov follow this link `https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4725`

Comment: @Abhishek, i've already seen that issue before creating this one

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install @angular/cli@latest --save-dev
```